# JMeter throwing 'File never reserved' error

Tags: csv, jmeter, web-api-testing

While running the JMeter for data driven testing, JMeter is thrown with the error below. A big chunk of data was not pulled in. CSV file has about 1500 email ids and would like to ramp up the test to a million. However, the test is failing at the first attempt itself.

Any thoughts, please. Appreciate your help.

```
2019-03-19 23:55:08,169 ERROR o.a.j.c.CSVDataSet: java.io.IOException: File never reserved: C:\Users\sp\Desktop\STM\STM-JMeterTests\emailAdd.csv
2019-03-19 23:55:08,572 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: emailAdd 1-5
2019-03-19 23:55:08,572 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: emailAdd 1-5
2019-03-19 23:55:08,594 ERROR o.a.j.c.CSVDataSet: java.io.IOException: File never reserved: C:\Users\sp\Desktop\STM\STM-JMeterTests\emailAdd.csv
2019-03-19 23:55:08,595 ERROR o.a.j.c.CSVDataSet: java.io.IOException: File never reserved: C:\Users\sp\Desktop\STM\STM-JMeterTests\emailAdd.csv
2019-03-19 23:55:08,607 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: emailAdd 1-4
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show your CSV Data Set configuration ? Thank you

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK, I have added the screen capture for CSV Data Set Configuration.

Comment: can you share jmeter.log ?

Comment: Looks like I cannot attach the logs. Logs are big. How can I share ?

Comment: did you try pastebin or similar services ?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have it in Pastebin now. Here is the link for the same :

http://dpaste.com/0P1SW3K

Comment: Thanks but you pasted only part of file. Could you paste it all, otherwise restart test and exit as soon as you have this log appear

Comment: Looks like that's all it printed in the log console for errors. I tried to look for the log files for this run, but didn't have that luck. Any thoughts, how best I can run this test to log everything to a file ?